# integral of modified bessel function of 2nd type

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, improper-integrals

I need some help on a possible way to integrate this:

$$
\int_0^\infty{x^{m-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda x}\left[\frac{\operatorname{K}_\nu\left(b\sqrt{\alpha+\beta x}\right)}{\left(b\sqrt{\alpha+\beta x}\right)^\nu}\right]}\mathrm{d}x
$$
where $m$, $\lambda$, $b$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ are constants and $\operatorname{K}_\nu(\cdot)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second type.

Comment: What is the background of this question? What have you tried? I converted your picture into latex form; please check that I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: Did you mean $\alpha + \beta x$ instead of $\alpha+\beta \gamma$ in the denominator of the integrand?

Comment: @Eckhard: this is related to comm. channels. I tried change of variable and assumed z=b*sqrt(alpha+beta*x), but the integral got worse.

Comment: @Sasha: Yes, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Maple has this special case in terms of the Meijer G function:
$$
\int _{0}^{1}\!{x}^{m-1}{{\rm K}_\nu\left(b\sqrt {\beta\,x}\right)}
 \left( b\sqrt {\beta\,x} \right) ^{-\nu}{dx}={2}^{-3+2\,m-\nu}
 \left( b\sqrt {\beta} \right) ^{-2\,m}{b}^{2}\beta\,
G^{2, 1}_{1, 3}\left(\frac{\beta{b}^{2}}{4}\, \Big\vert\,^{0}_{m-1-\nu, m-1, -1}\right)
$$
assuming $\nu$ is a positive integer.